# Deque iterator not decrementable

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I try to run this code with MSVC 2017:

```cxx
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

class StripPtR {
public:
    int i;
    StripPtR (int i) : i(i) {}
};

typedef std::deque<StripPtR> StripType;
typedef std::vector<StripType> StripsType;

int main(int, char**) {
    StripType a{ {1}, {2}, {3} };

    a.insert(a.end(), a.rbegin() + 1, a.rend());

    return 0;
}
```

And I get this error:

*Deque iterator not decrementable*

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8CAe.png)

The error occurs at runtime. During compile time there is no error or warning.

The same code works fine with GCC.

What is wrong?

Comment: Look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/insert) and you'll find "The behavior is undefined if first and last are iterators into `*this`".

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to re-insert elements which are already in the container. As I understand your example, it applies to (4) in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/insert. So, `a.rbegin()` and `a.rend()` _reference_ the elements to be inserted. These will _not_ be copies, but the elements themselves.

Comment: @molbdnilo Good point. Thanks for that reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::deque::insert` says:

> All iterators, including the past-the-end iterator, are invalidated.

The MSVC version probably loops through, incrementing/decrementing `first` (or `a.rbegin() + 1` in your code) which means that the insert works but afterwards these iterators are invalidated and cause your runtime error. This version results in that you can't pass iterators to the same container you `insert` into.